# Convert table to fit print layout width

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010

I have a bunch of word docs that I've converted from HTML, which look OK in web layout, but when we switch to print layout, they are chopped off on the right hand side. I have a macro I use to convert from html to docx and then save the linked images inline, but I'm not sure how to force the tables to fit the width of the page.

Comment: It looks like I can do something like : Selection.Tables(1).Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=468.45, RulerStyle:= _
        wdAdjustNone  is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up basically doing Selection.Tables(1).Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=468.45, RulerStyle:= _ wdAdjustNone  along with some other stuff. Not sure if it's the best way but seems to work.